# Algorithm for Skew Normal Form of an Antisymmetric Integer Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, algorithms

I'm hoping someone knows of an algorithm for computing the Skew Normal Form of an integer valued antisymmetric matrix. The Skew Normal Form is close cousin of the Smith Normal Form:

For an $N\times N$ antisymmetric matrix $M=-M^T$ of rank $r$ there exists some non unique integer matrix $V$ with $Det(V)=\pm1$ such that $$VMV^T=\oplus_{i=1}^{r/2} \begin{pmatrix}0 &-d_i\\ d_i&0
\end{pmatrix} \otimes 0_{N-r}$$

I hoping to apply a technique introduced in this paper, https://arxiv.org/pdf/1507.08966.pdf, which cites a book called "Integer Matrices" by Morris Newman. Unfortunately I have not been able to track down a copy.

Answer (score 1):

Pages 56-60 in Newman

I did an example of the first type of reduction in gp-pari, two operations to clear out the first column and first row, except for one element that is now the gcd of the original first row. 
Note that $$6 \cdot 1 + 10 \cdot (-2) + 15 \cdot 1 = 1$$
and see that $(1,-2,1)$ appears as part of a column in the matrix I call $p.$

Then we would repeat for the square submatrix with columns 2 to 4 and rows 2 to 4. He's got some separate steps if the final tri-diagonal matrix is not in proper Smith order.

============================

```
parisize = 4000000, primelimit = 500000
? s = [ 0,6,10,15; 0,0,20,30;0,0,0,45; 0,0,0,0]
%1 = 
[0 6 10 15]

[0 0 20 30]

[0 0  0 45]

[0 0  0  0]

? st = mattranspose(s)
%2 = 
[ 0  0  0 0]

[ 6  0  0 0]

[10 20  0 0]

[15 30 45 0]




? s -= st
%10 = 
[  0   6  10 15]

[ -6   0  20 30]

[-10 -20   0 45]

[-15 -30 -45  0]


? p = [ 1,0,0,0; 0,1,0,0;0,-2,1,0; 0,1,0,1]
%5 = 
[1  0 0 0]

[0  1 0 0]

[0 -2 1 0]

[0  1 0 1]

? matdet(p)
%6 = 1
? pt = mattranspose(p)
%7 = 
[1 0  0 0]

[0 1 -2 1]

[0 0  1 0]

[0 0  0 1]



? pt * s * p
%12 = 
[  0  1  10  15]

[ -1  0 -25 -60]

[-10 25   0  45]

[-15 60 -45   0]

? q = [ 1,0,0,0; 0,1, -10,-15; 0,0,1,0; 0,0,0,1] 
%13 = 
[1 0   0   0]

[0 1 -10 -15]

[0 0   1   0]

[0 0   0   1]

? qt = mattranspose(q)
%14 = 
[1   0 0 0]

[0   1 0 0]

[0 -10 1 0]

[0 -15 0 1]

? qt * pt * s * p * q
%15 = 
[ 0  1    0   0]

[-1  0  -25 -60]

[ 0 25    0 270]

[ 0 60 -270   0]
```

==============================

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response! So I should say I'm a physicist with little experience in writing algorithms in efficient way. From my perspective it seems like the main issue in adapting Newman's proof to an iterative algorithm is figuring out how to get a computer to generate the matrix U(or p in your notation) for me. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: @JSull I suspect you are asking about this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3251882/how-to-complete-a-primitive-vector-to-a-unimodular-matrix

Answer (score 0):

Alright, here is a worked example: given a column vector of integers, with gcd known to be $1,$ **how to construct an integer matrix with determinant $1$ and the given vector as the first column?**  Also note that each step involved an integer matrix $r_i$ with determinant $1.$ I did not stick entirely with "elementary matrices. Nevertheless, the invers of each could be easily constructed, call it $q_i,$  with $q_i r_i = r_i q_i = I.$ Then the inverse of $r_4 r_3 r_2 r_1$ is just $q_1 q_2 q_3 q_4$

```
PARI/GP is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and comes WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY WHATSOEVER.

Type ? for help, \q to quit.
Type ?12 for how to get moral (and possibly technical) support.

parisize = 4000000, primelimit = 500000



? v = [ 30; 42; 70; 105]
%1 = 
[ 30]

[ 42]

[ 70]

[105]

? r1 = [ 3,-2,0,0; -1,1,0,0; 0,0,1,0; 0,0,0,1]
%2 = 
[ 3 -2 0 0]

[-1  1 0 0]

[ 0  0 1 0]

[ 0  0 0 1]

? v1 = r1 * v
%3 = 
[  6]

[ 12]

[ 70]

[105]

? r2 = [ 12,0,-1,0; 0,1,0,0; -11,0,1,0; 0,0,0,1]
%4 = 
[ 12 0 -1 0]

[  0 1  0 0]

[-11 0  1 0]

[  0 0  0 1]

? v2 = r2 * v1 
%5 = 
[  2]

[ 12]

[  4]

[105]

? r3 = [ 53,0,0,-1; 0,1,0,0; 0,0,1,0; -52,0,0,1]
%6 = 
[ 53 0 0 -1]

[  0 1 0  0]

[  0 0 1  0]

[-52 0 0  1]

? matdet(r3)
%7 = 1
? v3 = r3 * v2 
%8 = 
[ 1]

[12]

[ 4]

[ 1]

? r4 = [ 1,0,0,0; -12,1,0,0; -4,0,1,0; -1,0,0,1]
%9 = 
[  1 0 0 0]

[-12 1 0 0]

[ -4 0 1 0]

[ -1 0 0 1]

? v4 = r4 * v3  
%10 = 
[1]

[0]

[0]

[0]

? r_full = r4 * r3 * r2 * r1
%11 = 
[  1908 -1272 -53 -1]

[-22897 15265 636 12]

[ -7665  5110 213  4]

[ -3780  2520 105  2]

? v
%12 = 
[ 30]

[ 42]

[ 70]

[105]

? r_full * v
%13 = 
[1]

[0]

[0]

[0]

? matdet(r_full)
%14 = 1
? 
? unimodular = matadjoint(r_full) 
%15 = 
[ 30 2  1  1]

[ 42 3  1  1]

[ 70 0 12 11]

[105 0  0 53]

? matdet(unimodular)
%16 = 1
? 
?
```