# Show that skew symmetric A and B are congruent

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

$\text{Let}\ \ A,B\in M_n\ \ \text{be skew symmetric. Show that there is a nonsingular}\ \ S\in M_n\ \ \text{such that}$
$A = SBS^T\ \ \text{if and only if}\ \ rankA = rankB. $

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem? What have you tried? Were you able to show the "only if" part of this result?

Comment: Are you aware [Sylvester's law of inertia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia), which is a similar result for symmetric and Hermitian matrices?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I tried using the spectral theorem. If you know what need to change in this law of inertia to solve my problem above, can you tell me please? I don't understand at well. I really need help.

Comment: The surprise is that there is an algorithm to take a skew symmetric matrix to a modified Smith form, skew symmetric with nonzero elements only as $c_{i, i+1}$   and  $c_{i+1,i}.$ It's in Integral Matrices by Newman. Compared to usual Smith form, the fact that this can be constructed as $P^T AP$ is, unusual

Comment: found it, chapter 4, section 3. He calls it the skew normal form; pages 56-60

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3539767/algorithm-for-skew-normal-form-of-an-antisymmetric-integer-matrix

Comment: I'd suggest interpreting $A$ and $B$ as representing skew bilinear forms -- then adapting Gram Schmidt to skew bilinear forms, and running it.  This is essentially the approach outlined in the bilinear forms chapter in Artin's *Algebra*. If you are careful with definitions of skew, then the result holds over any field.

Answer (score 0):

This is a partial answer which I hope will be of some use. There are two general approaches that come to mind, both rely on the idea of showing that a rank-$2k$ skew-symmetric matrix is [congruent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_congruence) to some canonical form.

Noting that $A$ must have even rank, let $k = \frac 12 \operatorname{rank}(A)$.

**Option 1:**

- Noting that $iA$ is Hermitian (where $i^2 = -1$), apply the either spectral theorem or Sylvester's law of inertia to conclude that there exists a non-singular matrix $S_1$ with complex entries for which $S_1AS_1^*$ has the form $\operatorname{diag}(iI_k,-iI_k,0)$.
- Using this, conclude that there exists a non-singular matrix $S_2$ such that $S_2AS_2^*$ has the form
  $$ 
  S_2AS_2^* = \pmatrix{0&I_k&0\\-I_k&0&0\\0&0&0}
  $$
- It now suffices to show that if $SAS^* = B$ has a complex, non-singular solution $S$, then it must also have a real, non-singular solution $S$.  Unfortunately, I don't see a quick approach here.

**Option 2:**

- Show that if $A$ is skew-symmetric with $A^2 = -I_{2k}$, then $A$ is orthogonally similar to $\operatorname{diag}(C_k,0)$ with
  $$
  C_k = \pmatrix{0&I_k\\-I_k&0}.
  $$
- Show that if $A$ is skew-symmetric with $A^2 = \operatorname{diag}(0,-\lambda_1 I_{2k_1}, \dots, -\lambda_m I_{2k_m})$ with $0<\lambda_1 < \cdots < \lambda_m$, then $A = \operatorname{diag}(A_0,A_1,\dots,A_m)$ with $A_j^2 = \lambda_j I_{2k_j}$.
- Using the spectral theorem, conclude that $A$ is orthogonally similar to $\operatorname{diag}(0, \lambda_1 C_{k_1},\dots, \lambda_{m}C_{k_m})$.
- If $M = \operatorname{diag}(0, \lambda_1 C_{k_1},\dots, \lambda_{m}C_{k_m})$, show that there is a non-singular $S$ such that $SMS^T = \operatorname{diag}(C_k,0)$. Combine with what was said so far conclude that there exists such a matrix $S$ with $SAS^T = \operatorname{diag}(C_k,0)$.

Comment: Actually, Horn and Johnson's *Matrix Analysis* give a nice proof of this that relies on the "real Schur form" (see Theorems 2.3.3 and 2.5.8 Second Edition). If I find time, I'll adapt their proof into a self-contained answer.