# gcd of two linear functions with same slope?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The general question I'm trying to answer is how to (if possible),
given $M$ integer vectors of length $N$ where $M < N$,
where the $gcd$ of each vector is $1$,
construct an $N\times N$ unimodular matrix, where the first $M$ rows are the $M$ vectors.

For example, say $N = 3$, $M=1$, and our vector is $\begin{bmatrix}6 & 10 & 15\end{bmatrix}$
a valid matrix would be:
$\begin{bmatrix}
6 & 10 & 15\\
0 & 1 & 1\\
1 & -1 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}$
or, if given $\begin{bmatrix}102& 190& 345\end{bmatrix}$, an acceptable answer is:
$\begin{bmatrix}
102 & 190 & 345\\
0 & 1 & 1\\
25 & -38 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$

FWIW, among the space of possible solutions when infinitely many exist, the maximum number of 0s and probably also smaller absolute value of the scalars are also preferable.

Currently, I only have a few specific, not-so-general solutions.
E.g., if $N = 3$ and $M = 1$, we first try and find the second row.
Say we have $\begin{bmatrix}a& b& c\end{bmatrix}$, and let the second row be $\begin{bmatrix}x& y& z\end{bmatrix}$.
If we arbitrarily let $x=1$, then we can subtract $a$ times the second row from the first without changing the determinant of the final matrix, meaning unimodularity should be preserved (this can be reversed later; we're just trying to find valid values for $y$ and $z$).
If we do so, we get $\begin{bmatrix}0 & b - a\cdot y & c - a\cdot z\end{bmatrix}$ as the first row.
For the matrix to be unimodular, we must have $gcd$ of each row be $1$, so we require

$\text{gcd}(b - a\cdot y, c - a\cdot z) = 1$

From here, I'm not quite sure what to do.
Given particular values, we can try a series of checks, e.g. if $\text{gcd}(b,c) = 1$, then $y=z=0$ is a valid solution.
But I'm not sure how to find if this is solve-able, or if it is, the family of solutions from here.

Then, I am also not sure how to generalize this to larger problems.
My idea there is to try row reduction with row and column pivoting to build diagonal blocks as we iteratively append rows, and maintain a determinant of $\pm 1$ for each of these diagonal blocks.
If the blocks can be kept small enough (e.g $\le 3$), then a series of specific solutions for those block sizes may be enough.
I'm open to any ideas, thoughts, suggestions!

EDIT:
Here is a simple implementation in the Julia programming language implementing lonza leggiera's approach:

```
using AbstractAlgebra, LinearAlgebra
function unimod(A)
    M, N = size(A)
    MS = MatrixSpace(ZZ, M, N)
    S, T, U = snf_with_transform(MS(A))
    S = Matrix(S)
    all(isone, @views S[diagind(S)]) || throw(ArgumentError("Not possible!"))
    Uinv = Int.(inv(U.//1))
    [Int.(inv(T.//1)) * Uinv[1:M, :]; Uinv[M+1:end, :]]
end
```

A few examples:

````
julia> unimod([6 8 15]).//1 |> det |> Int
1

julia> unimod([6 8 15; 1 1 0]).//1 |> det |> Int
-1

julia> unimod([1 0 0; 1 2 2])
ERROR: ArgumentError: Not possible!
```
````

Comment: Please do not use codeblocks instead of the appropriate formatting (in MathJax or emphasis).

Comment: The case $M=1$ is discussed at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3251882/how-to-complete-a-primitive-vector-to-a-unimodular-matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to extend an $\ M\times N\ $ matrix with integer entries to a unimodular matrix if and only if all its elementary divisors are $\ 1\ $—that is, if and only if its [Smith normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form) is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
I_{M\times M}&0_{M\times(N-M)}
\end{bmatrix}\ .
$$
This is not necessarily true just because the greatest common divisors of all its rows are $\ 1\ $.  The greatest common divisors of both rows if the matrix
$$
\pmatrix{1&0&0\\1&2&2}
$$
are $\ 1\ $, for example, but its Smith normal form is
$$
\pmatrix{1&0&0\\0&2&0}\ ,
$$
so it doesn't have a unimodular extension.

To prove the above assertion, first note that if all the elementary divisors of $\ A\ $ are $\ 1\ $, then there exist an $\ M\times M $ unimodular matrix $\ U\ $ and an $\ N\times N $ unimodular matrix $\ V\ $ such that
$$
UAV=\begin{bmatrix}
I_{M\times M}&0_{M\times(N-M)}
\end{bmatrix}\ .
$$
Let $\ W_1\ $ be the $\ M\times N\ $ matrix formed by the first $\ M\ $ rows of $\ V^{-1}\ $, and $\ W_2\ $ the $\ (N-M)\times N\ $ matrix formed by its last $\ N-M\ $ rows. Then
$$
\pmatrix{U^{-1}&0_{M\times(N-M)}\\
0_{(N-M)\times M}&I_{(N-M)\times(N-M)}}V^{-1}=\pmatrix{U^{-1}W_1\\W_2}
$$
is a unimodular matrix.  But $\ U^{-1}W_1=A\ $, so  $\ \pmatrix{A\\W_2}\ $ is its required unimodular extension.

Now suppose that $\ A\ $ has an extension to an $\ N\times N\ $ unimodular matrix $\ B\ $.  Then $\ A\ $ must be non singular, and therefore all its elementary divisors must be non-zero. Let $\ d\ $ be any elementary divisor of $\ A\ $.  Then $\ d\ $ must divide the $\ M^\text{th}\ $ elementary divisor of $\ A\ $, which is in turn a divisor of all the $\ M\times M\ $ minors of $\ A\ $. If $\ B_i\ $ is the $\ (M+i)\times N\ $ matrix formed by the first $\ M+i\ $ rows of $\ B\ $ then every $\ (M+1)\times(M+1) $ minor of $\ B_1\ $ is an integer linear combination of the $\ M\times M\ $ minors of $\ A\ $, and so must be divisible by $\ d\ $.  Likewise, every $\ (M+i)\times(M+i) $ minor of $\ B_i\ $ is an integer linear combination of the $\ (M+i-1)\times(M+i-1)\ $ minors of $\ B_{i-1}\ $, so, by induction, all these minors  must be divisible divisible by $\ d\ $. It follows that $\ d\ $ must divide the determinant of $\ B_{N-M}=B\ $.  But since $\ B\ $ is unimodular, its determinant must be $\ {\pm}1\ $, and $\ d\ $ must be $\ 1\ $.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks, this is constructive. I added a simple example implementing this answer to the question (so that I can add code blocks). This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Hermite normal form should be enough/equivalent given that our matrix is in fact unimodular.
Let H = A*V, and then proceed exactly as you described here for Smith normal form, letting U=I.

In Hermite normal form, the diagonals are positive, we have 0s above the diagonal, and non-negative numbers strictly smaller than the diagonals below.
All diagonals should be 1, forcing those "strictly smaller" off diagonals to 0.

Hermite normal form is computationally better. For one thing, Smith normal form algorithms often depend on Hermite normal form.

Comment: That's a nice observation.  I didn't realise that you could reach the Smith normal form of a matrix with unit elementary divisors with just column operations alone.